# How to set up the filepath in code to make it runnable for others

Tags: python

I build a small project in python, now I need to send to another user to make him run it. But if he downloads my code on his computer then the file path(which based on my computer) won't be valid anymore. Is there anything I can do to make it runnable for him by setting up the path correctly?

Comment: Search with the keywords "absolute path" and "relative path"

Answer (score 1):

zip the folder that it is located in and have them place it in the same location i.e if it is in your documents folder have them place it there

Comment: If you zip it you could just use relative paths.